# Is there a function in the POSIX APIs for tracking the mouse position in the console?

Tags: c, posix

Do the POSIX APIs provide a function to track where the mouse is in relation to the console? (For example, in Vim and derivatives, clicking and dragging selects that text in Visual mode.)

Comment: I'm not sure if POSIX even mentions the word 'mouse'.

Comment: Turns out it does, once. *In addition, mixed scope is particularly useful in a window server where one thread with high priority and system scope handles the mouse so that it tracks well.*

Answer (score 3):

The POSIX API has no mouse-related functions or options. Console programs that interact with mice have to do so via OS-specific methods or non-POSIX libraries.

Comment: For example, [libgpm](https://www.nico.schottelius.org/software/gpm/) on Linux OSes.